# Openshift with Geoserver and PostGIS DB configured...now what?

Tags: openshift, geoserver

I've set up geoserver and a POSTGIS DB on openshift.  I can confirm that I have data in the DB because I can connect to it with QGIS and add layers....Now I am trying to create a simple map with one layer but can not find any tutorials on this... The below code works with a local instance of data to create a simple map...What url do I use for the layers I created on openshift? I can't seem to find them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>OGR2Layers</title>
<style>
 #map{width:400px;height:400px;}
</style>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/2.13/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map, selectsControls
function init(){
    var option = {
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    };
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', option);
    var attribution = {attribution:"&copy; <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"};
    olmapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap Mapnik", "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", attribution);
    map.addLayer(olmapnik);
    map.setBaseLayer(olmapnik);
    var ls= new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(); 
    map.addControl(ls); 
    ls.maximizeControl(); 
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
    var block = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("block GeoJSON", {
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "block.GeoJSON",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        strategies: [
            new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()
        ]
    });
    map.addLayer(block);
    extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-97.640446,21.693337,-80.768595,32.375889).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
    map.zoomToExtent(extent);
};
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1>this is a test</h1>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you added the postgis tables to GeoServer? - if so then look at http://....openshift.com/geoserver - to see the geoserver home page - the links on the right give the getCapablities page which has links for wms layers

Comment: Yes.I can preview it Im trying to figure out which url I am suppose to use in my `var block` in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/vector-wfs.html), I think you need something like with `http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver` changed to the domain you gave to your openshift instance:

```
// format used to parse WFS GetFeature responses
var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
        'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
        '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
    // use jsonp: false to prevent jQuery from adding the "callback"
    // parameter to the URL
    $.ajax({url: url, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: false});
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
    maxZoom: 19
  }))
});
```